# Is ‘done’ a shortened form of ‘who is done’ or a modifier of ‘you’?

Tags: word-meaning

> But before Harry could answer, Madam Malkin said, "That's you
>   **done**, my dear," and Harry, not sorry for an excuse to stop talking to the boy, hopped down from the footstool.
>
> (Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone)

Is ‘done’ a shortened form of ‘who is done’ or a modifier of ‘you’?

Comment: This appears to be an odd colloquialism used by the author. Without more context, the meaning is entirely unclear, and I don't know that the phrase has either of the two meanings you suggested. It *might* mean something along the lines of "You are done now, my dear" or "I am done dealing with/doing something to you, my dear". Without any idea of who Madam Malkin is or why Harry was standing on the footstool, this is impossible to answer.

Comment: It isn't odd in British English. It means that whatever operation was  being performed is now complete.

Comment: @KenB: Madam Malkin sells wizards' robes. She was fitting Harry Potter for his first robe while this snippet of conversation took place.

Comment: @KenB: As Barrie says, the construction is perfectly common in BrE. But the usage figures in [this NGram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=that%27s+me+finished&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=) suggest it's only really been common for about 50 years, and it's still less common in US than UK usage. I doubt it's considered that "odd" by all Americans though, or the publishers would probably have changed it in US editions of the book (they did that for most "Briticisms").

Comment: @All: My apologies for the improper assumption. Interestingly, though, if the NGram that FumbleFingers linked is altered to look for "that's me done", it returns far fewer results, beginning more recently, and if it's changed to "that's you done" [it finds exactly zero results](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=that%27s+you+done&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=0&share=), even in British English. Interpret it how you like, I suppose.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I think the "translators" messed up on that one.  It's definitely *very unusual* in AmE.

Comment: @snailplane: I'm intrigued. So far as I can see, *"That's you done"* is the same basic construction as *"That's it! I'm outta here!"*. Or more specifically, ["That's me out!"](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=that%27s+me+out&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=), which NGrams flatlines for the UK corpus (I most often hear that one in American movies when a character is cleaned out in a poker game). The specific words **you done** are a trivial/irrelevant variation on a theme, to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously ***done*** here *is* a "modifier" of "you" - I don't see how it could be otherwise, regardless of whether we imagine replacing it with *who is done* (or more likely, *sorted, dealt with, finished*, etc.).

In fact, it wouldn't make any difference *what* word we used to replace ***done***. In all cases you could interpret the modifier as meaning ***who is*** dealt with, **who is** finished, etc. Effectively...

> *"That's you XXXX'ed"*
>    ...is an idiomatic construction meaning...
>    *"[There!] You have been XXXX'ed"* (or *"You are XXXX'ed"*)

---

Per my comment to the question itself, and [this NGram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=that%27s%20me%20finished&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=), this idiomatic conversion of *[noun] is [verbed]* to *that's [noun] [verbed]* has only really gained traction in the past 50 years or so, and it does seem to be more common in British than American English even today.

But I doubt most Americans would find it "odd", given that it's the same basic construction as...

> *["That's that then"](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=that%27s%20that%20then&year_start=1920&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=)* (idiomatic expression usually meaning *That's finished, That's all there is to it*, etc.)

...which, if that NGram link is to be believed, occurs just as often in AmE as BrE.

Comment: I looked at the link you supplied for **that 's me finished** in the AmE corpus.  There are few enough results that you can check them by hand by clicking the search links at the bottom.  I clicked the most recent (1983-1993) and checked all the results on the first page (out of 3 total).  Not one was *actually* from an AmE source.  This doesn't surprise me much.

Comment: @snailplane: After a bit more checking I'm definitely getting the feeling Americans don't often use *"That's [pronoun] [descriptor]"* "figuratively" (as in *"That's us out of the tournament, then."*, after losing a critical game). US instances of *"That's me [blah blah]"* almost always turn out to be "direct/spatial" references (said while pointing at a photo of me doing something or being somewhere, for example). I've [asked about this on ELU](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/111070/) - it does look like a significant US/UK divide.